# What might be the cause of the weird colors and picture mis-alignment?

Tags: hdmi, external-display

If I connect my Android tablet (A10MID, Android 4.0) to my monitor, and:

- the colors on the monitor
- the alignment of the picture
- the resolution
- and the floating "input not support"-ed message

are problematic. It works well otherwise: mouse, keyboard, runs apps, ...

Here is the setup:

```
tablet miniHDMI -> miniHDMI-HDMI cable -> HDMI_female to DVI_male adapter -> monitor DVI
```

And this is what I get:

[image: img]

(higher resolution: http://postimage.org/image/5tdvmb5pz/)

Since then I tried that monitor connected to my desktop with DVI-DVI cable that I borrowed, and it works perfectly.

I also went down to the next electronics store to try the tablet with a different display, and my tablet seems to work with one of those fancy new TVs through HDMI.

So both the tablet and the monitor work perfectly. But they cannot be coupled.

Could this be caused by my monitor not supporting HDCP (High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection)?

If not, than my HDMI-to-DVI adapter is the only thing that can be the cause of this?

Comment: Th image is unclear. Please try to upload a better one.

Comment: Could this be an issue with HDMI encryption that DVI does not suppport?
If so, can I remove that "feature" of android?

Comment: @user1358 / nlognfan Please register an account to maintain ownership of your posts.  Once you do, use this to get your unregistered accounts merged into it: http://android.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different resolutions on the Android video source and changing the refresh rate between 50 Hz and 60 Hz. My cheapie tablet offers:
1920 x 1080p 50 Hz
1920 x 1080p 60 Hz
1280 x 720p 50 Hz
1280 x 720p 60 Hz
720 x 576p 50 Hz
720 x 576p 60 Hz
All choices under Settings-->HDMI-->HDMI Resolution.
My guess is that you are sending a higher resolution than the target can handle.